# Sparse_hash_map iteration

Tags: c++, hash, dictionary, iterator, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to figure out how google sparse_hash_map works.
I've got the declaration right and populating it. However, I'm having trouble iterating over and displaying the map.
I want to print the  pairs in order to check if the computations are correct. My declaration is:

```
sparse_hash_map<int*, double **, hash<int*>, eqstr> q_table;
```

I'm trying to do the iteration on a for loop as

```
for(sparse_hash_map<int*, double **, hash<int*>, eqstr>::iterator it = q_table.begin(); it != q_table.end(); ++it)
```

I've tried doing `int* key = it[0]` but doesn't work, neither does `int* key = it.first`. Even tried `int* key = it.key()`... Though nothing of these sorts are in the documentation.

I couldn't figure out from the docs provided and I can't find examples...

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is an example of using an iterator at the end of this page:  http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/sparse_hash_map.html

Comment: @carl Thank you so much. I missed that. I ended up doing something like `int * state = it->first; double ** action_value = q_table[state]; // print whatever... `. Not most efficient I assume but works for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it implements an interface consistent with the standard library did you try something like:

```
int * state = it->first;
double ** action_value = it->second;
```

You have to use the arrow because normally when you dereference an iterator you get a `value_type` of the container element, and for associative containers this is usually some sort of `pair` with `first` and `second` members.